# Modify function to accept tables as well (Python 3)

Tags: python, list

I've designed a simple function that looks at an inputted list of numbers, identifies the minimum and maximum values, then substitutes both of them for the midpoint value between them, the function is here:

```
def mainfunction(list_of_numbers):

    smallest_number = list_of_numbers[0]
    for a in list_of_numbers:
        if a < smallest_number:
            smallest_number = a

    largest_number = list_of_numbers[0]
    for b in list_of_numbers:
        if b > largest_number:
            largest_number = b

    midpoint = (smallest_number + largest_number)/2

    final_list = [x if (x != largest_number and x != smallest_number) else midpoint for x in list_of_numbers]
    return final_list

print(mainfunction([10, 7, 14, 3, -200, 8, 1, -12, 250]))
```

Unfortunately, I can't get the function to work on TABLES of numbers, is there an easy way to convert a table of numbers into a list? Any info would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: what do you mean by table? is it nested list?

Comment: Oh crap sorry, it's a list of lists, so yes it's a NESTED LIST, my fault should've clarified. So basically I would want to convert:

[[3,4], [15,16], [19,20]] 

INTO,

[3, 4, 15, 16, 19, 20]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[3,4], [15,16], [19,20]]
res = list(chain.from_iterable(a))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 15, 16, 19, 20]
```

with list comprehension

```
res = [x for lst in a for x in lst]
```

Comment: @Programming55 for finding min and max you can use builtin methods `min()` and `max()`